# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I had a question that was on hold with a -1 vote. The vote increased to 0, presumably due to my edit. However, I see that it has been closed. I'm unclear as to why. The question is here:

[Torsion and submanifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137023)

Comment: On hold is automatically changed to closed after 5 days unless 5 users vote to take it off hold (those same people can vote to reopen after it has been closed too). On hold is the same as closed in all respects as far as I know, apart from the name. Since it was closed as off-topic, I doubt people will find the edit has made it on-topic.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 8):

Since that question has a bit of a messy history of edits and an accepted question, I recommend that you leave it closed, but post a new question.  Before you do, make sure to take some time to ask a focused and well-motivated question (perhaps you have an example where that is preserved by torsion, and want to know how general it is...).  And don't forget to read [How To Ask page](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/70/how-to-ask-page).